# Iterate over map with lists in terraform 0.12

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I am using terraform 0.12.8 and I am trying to write a resource which would iterate over the following variable structure:

```
variable "applications" {
  type        = map(string)
  default = {
    "app1" = "test,dev,prod"
    "app2" = "dev,prod"
  }
}
```

My resource:

```
resource "aws_iam_user" "custom" {
  for_each = var.applications

  name = "circleci-${var.tags["ServiceType"]}-user-${var.tags["Environment"]}-${each.key}"
  path = "/"
}
```

So, I can iterate over my map. However, I can't figure out how to verify that `var.tags["Environment"]` is enabled for specific app e.g. `app1`.

Basically, I want to ensure that the resource is created for each application as long as the Environment variable is in the list referencing app name in the applications map.

Could someone help me out here?

Please note that I am happy to go with a different variable structure if you have something to propose that would accomplish my goal.

Comment: So essentially an expansion of `regex(var.tags["Environment"], each.value)`?

Comment: I was thinking of using maybe contains(["test,dev,prod"], each.value). However, I don't know how to iterate over it. Regex is something I haven't considered.

Comment: `contains` would not work for you unless you split your strings into lists first, at which point you are executing multiple function invocations when a single regex would suffice. You could use that in a ternary with the `false` condition being a `null`, but really you need the entire resource to not exist on that conditional.